Heroku Searchkick Looking on Localhost for Elasticsearch. Won't Use Bonsai ENV Variable
STACK I AM USING: Rails 7, Heroku, PostGreSQL, Bonsai, Elasticsearch, Searchkick
GEMS I AM USING:
# Ransack for search
gem 'ransack'

# SearchKick for search
# Elasticsearch for autocomplete
# Bonsai for heroku Elasticsearch
gem 'searchkick'
gem 'elasticsearch', '~>7.17'
gem 'bonsai-elasticsearch-rails', '~> 7'
gem 'elasticsearch-model', github: 'elastic/elasticsearch-rails', branch: 'main'
gem 'elasticsearch-rails', github: 'elastic/elasticsearch-rails', branch: 'main'

HERE IS THE DEBUG CODE OUTPUT SHOWING THAT THE BONSAI URL IS INDEED BEING FETCHED FROM HEROKU:
remote:
remote: -----> Installing node-v20.9.0-linux-x64
remote: -----> Installing yarn-v1.22.19
remote: -----> Detecting rake tasks
remote: -----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
remote:        Running: rake assets:precompile
remote:        BONSAI_URL BEFORE: https://*********:****2@**-******.us-east-1.bonsaisearch.net:443
remote:        BONSAI_URL AFTER: https://*******:****2@**-******.us-east-1.bonsaisearch.net:443
remote:        yarn install v1.22.19
remote:        [1/4] Resolving packages...
remote:        [2/4] Fetching packages...
remote:        [3/4] Linking dependencies...

HERE IS THE ERROR OUTPUT WHEN TRYING TO CREATE A NEW CONTACT:
2024-04-15T14:55:10.407747+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2024-04-15T14:55:10.407675 #2]  INFO -- : [50bf87af-55bf-4d04-850c-d5f3a89b775e] Processing by ContactsController#create as TURBO_STREAM
2024-04-15T14:55:10.407833+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2024-04-15T14:55:10.407802 #2]  INFO -- : [50bf87af-55bf-4d04-850c-d5f3a89b775e]   Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"[FILTERED]", "contact"=>{"first_name"=>"Federico", "last_name"=>"De Favori", "date_first_met(2i)"=>"", "date_first_met(3i)"=>"", "date_first_met(1i)"=>"", "last_known_country_ids"=>[""], "last_known_city_ids"=>[""], "mobile_phone_1"=>"", "office_phone_1"=>"", "home_phone"=>"", "email_1"=>"", "website_1"=>"", "contact_apps"=>"", "birthday(2i)"=>"", "birthday(3i)"=>"", "birthday(1i)"=>"", "address_1"=>"", "how_we_met"=>"", "things_I_like"=>"", "best_memories"=>"", "areas_for_improvement"=>"", "notes"=>"", "contact_group_ids"=>[""], "contact_type_ids"=>[""], "office_phone_2"=>"", "other_phone"=>"", "email_2"=>"", "email_3"=>"", "email_4"=>"", "email_5"=>"", "website_2"=>"", "website_3"=>"", "website_4"=>"", "website_5"=>"", "website_6"=>"", "website_7"=>"", "website_8"=>"", "mobile_phone_2"=>"", "address_2"=>""}, "commit"=>"Create Contact"}
2024-04-15T14:55:10.435935+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2024-04-15T14:55:10.435852 #2]  INFO -- : [50bf87af-55bf-4d04-850c-d5f3a89b775e] Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 28ms (Searchkick: 6.5ms | ActiveRecord: 9.7ms | Allocations: 10238)
2024-04-15T14:55:10.436471+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2024-04-15T14:55:10.436430 #2] FATAL -- : [50bf87af-55bf-4d04-850c-d5f3a89b775e]
2024-04-15T14:55:10.436473+00:00 app[web.1]: [50bf87af-55bf-4d04-850c-d5f3a89b775e] Faraday::ConnectionFailed (Failed to open TCP connection to localhost:9200 (Connection refused - connect(2) for 127.0.0.1:9200)):
2024-04-15T14:55:10.436474+00:00 app[web.1]: [50bf87af-55bf-4d04-850c-d5f3a89b775e]
2024-04-15T14:55:10.436496+00:00 app[web.1]: [50bf87af-55bf-4d04-850c-d5f3a89b775e] app/controllers/contacts_controller.rb:53:in `block in create'

SEARCHKICK.RB

# Disable automatic indexing and importing in production
if Rails.env.production?
  Searchkick.disable_callbacks
end


BONSAI.RB

# Heroku elasticsearch with bonsai
puts "BONSAI_URL BEFORE: #{ENV['BONSAI_URL']}"
Elasticsearch::Model.client = Elasticsearch::Client.new url: ENV['BONSAI_URL'], log: true
puts "BONSAI_URL AFTER: #{ENV['BONSAI_URL']}"


NOTES

I have nothing in production.rb or development.rb referencing elasticsearch, searchkick, or bonsai
I am using the pagy gem, and in the pagy.rb initializer, I have:  require 'pagy/extras/elasticsearch_rails'


Are you setting Searchkick.client anywhere?

Only in bonsai.rb:
Elasticsearch::Model.client = Elasticsearch::Client.new url: ENV['BONSAI_URL'], log: true
Is that what you mean?  If not, then no.  And probably no, because that is setting the ElasticSearch client.  I'm not setting Searchkick.client.  What must I do for that?

Searchkick.client is what I meant because the title of your post is "Heroku Searchkick Looking..."

Do you have any recommendation on how to set Searchkick.client?  This is my first time using Searchkick, Elasticsearch, or Bonsai.  Thank you!

https://medium.com/@nerboda/integrating-elastic-search-with-rails-on-heroku-using-searchkick-and-bonsai-eb1aebbc6df7

Please don't SHOUT AT US. If you need to emphasize something you can do it with Markdown.

@dbugger Following the tutorial you linked to above, there appears to be some progress, but now I'm getting a new error:
FATAL -- : [c6d3f6d0-156c-4546-a7e8-5175d14c6835]
2024-04-18T13:37:40.040853+00:00 app[web.1]: [c6d3f6d0-156c-4546-a7e8-5175d14c6835] Elasticsearch::UnsupportedProductError (The client noticed that the server is not a supported distribution of Elasticsearch.):
Thanks in advance for any further guidance.

That's an entire other question

Okay, I will post another question.  Thank you for your time.
